# Ошибка в JavaScript или PHP

Tags: ajax, javascript, php

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Данный код не работает, что очень грустно.

```
function mona() {
    var id = <?=$_GET['id'];?>;
    var log = <?=$_SESSION['log'];?>;
    var url = "page_p.php?id="+escape(id)+"&log="+escape(log);

    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = mono; 
    request.send(null);
}

function mono() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('golos').innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    }
}

function ozoo() {
    var id = <?=$_GET['id'];?>;
    var url = "page_p.php?id="+escape(id)+"&ok=ok";

    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = napic; 
    request.send(null);
}

function napic(){
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('napic').innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    }
}

function ozon(){
    ozoo();
    mona();
}

function prov() {
    if (document.reg.chek[0].checked) {
        var chek = 1;
    }
    else if (document.reg.chek[1].checked) {
        var chek = 2;
    }
    else if (document.reg.chek[2].checked) {
        var chek = 3;
    }
    else if (document.reg.chek[3].checked) {
        var chek = 4;
    }
    else if (document.reg.chek[4].checked) {
        var chek = 5;
    }

    var id = document.reg.id.value;
    var url = "page_p.php?bym=ok&chek="+escape(chek)+"&id="+escape(id);

    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = otvet; 
    request.send(null);
}

function otvet() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            var ress = request.responseText;
            alert (ress);
            mona();
        }
    }
}
```

Или это проблема в PHP коде?

Comment: Ozon вызывается при загрузке страницы.

Comment: А что не работает-то?

Comment: не выводит данные...здесь 2 функции должны выводить оценку книг и панель и голосования.Но ответа нет.До того как была написана функция mona ...оценки выводились.

Comment: Проверьте, что возвращает скрипт page_p.php, возможно, проблема передаваемых ему параметрах.

Comment: Всем спасибо. Решил, правда, пока на половину, но главная проблема была в том, что если человек не был зарегистрирован, то получалось var log= ;

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте про JQuery, упростите себе жизнь. ) Всё можно будет написать в пару строк.

Вот, например, элементарный ajax запрос (язык javascript):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'google.com',
    data: {bym: 'ok', chek: 123},
    success: function(r) 
    {
        alert(r);
    }
});
```

Раз в 10 короче и понятнее самописанных функций. )

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, определена ли переменная "request", а также вручную проверьте ответ от page_p.php.

Comment: А как вручную проверить ответ от page_p.php?

Comment: все проверил..все пашет..буду искать проблему в выводе.